# como puedo abrir una con Window.open y mandar variables para usarlas en la nueva ventana?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, fetch

tengo el siguiente problema. estoy tratando de mandar el valor de mis variable `label_camara` y `id_vendor`, los cuales los cuales están contenidos en mi `FormData()` "ventanacam" de JS y usarlos en otra ventana llamada "POPUP.PHP" que sea creada con `window.open` y hacer uso de ellas.

```
                    document.getElementById("ventana").onclick = function(){
                    ventana();
                }
            
            function ventana() {
                
                const ventanacam = new FormData();
                
                ventanacam.append('label_camara','camara hd estandar');
                ventanacam.append('id_vendor','numero de vendor');
                
                    fetch("CAMARA/CAMARAS/popup.php", {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: ventanacam, 
                    }) 
                    .then(resultado => { 
                        
                        return resultado.text()
                    })
                    .then(ventanaemergente => {
                        
                        console.log(" se inicio ventana");
                        
                    })
            }
```

como pueden observar, he intentado ocupar fetch pero este solo llama a mi php para mandarle los datos, pero quisiera que se envíen los datos y trabajarlos en mi ventana "popup.php". ojala me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: podrias usar localStorage para almacenar las variables y manipularlas luego en otras ventanas

Comment: concuerdo con  @HernánGarcia, Si solo es para trabajarlos momentáneos, y no necesitas guardar en BDD, lo mejor es usar localStorage, así se te haría mucho mas facil.

Comment: muchas gracias a los dos, de hecho de saber que podía hacer eso, me hubiera ahorrado mucho código anteriormente, saludos a ambos y un abrazo.